# Linux Kali Debian initramfs due to disk inconsistency

Tags: initramfs, fsck

When i started UTM (Virtual Box) it opened BusyBox with (inittramfs) [image]

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: Hi jaja, your other question clearly suggests you're a beginner. So: **welcome to Linux**! Sadly, you literally chose the wrong platform: Kali is actively not *meant* for beginners, [as Kali says itself](https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/). Unlike other Linux distributions, which are general-purpose, Kali does one thing: being a pentesting tool, when you need something that disables as much networking as possible. So, pick literally any other Linux distro, and you'll probably have a better day without losing anything to learn or any other benefit.

Answer (score 1):

Just run:

```
fsck -fy /dev/vda2
```

if not OK afterward, your disk could be damaged, otherwise it should just boot.